# How to collect value from SQL table using powershell

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell-3.0

I am using following powershell commandlets to get a max value from a column

```
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=in2-akpatil;Database=TestDB;User             Id=sa;Password=********" 
    $SqlConnection.Open()
$query = "SELECT MAX( [TimeGenerated]) FROM [T_Windows_EventLogs] WHERE MachineName  LIKE '%Amit%'"
    $command = $SqlConnection.CreateCommand()
    $command.CommandText = $query
    $result =$command.ExecuteReader()
```

The OutPut is =>

```
FieldCount
----------
         1
```

Expected output is =>

```
2016-08-12 12:31:54.000
```

I want to store this in a powershell variable.

Where I am going wrong?

Comment: You are just executing the query, not parsing through the result. For a single value, you can use `ExecuteScalar`.

Comment: Try ExecuteNonQuery() instead of ExecuteReader()

Comment: Several things wrong here. 1) One **never** connects to a database as `sa`. 2) One also **never** stores passwords in clear text in a script. Always use Windows-integrated security to talk to the database server. 3) One **never** builds SQL by interpolating values into a string. Use query parameters to build a command. 4) You execute the query but never look at the result. There are many examples of how to do all that, even in Powershell syntax. I'm sure you find some if you look for them.

Comment: Yes, i will correct it .......

Answer (score 0):

Using Execute reader we need to parse each and every row returned. The below code will help doing that.

`while ($result.Read()) {
    Write-Output $result['TimeGenerated'];}`

Answer (score 0):

@Karan and @gofr1 
It worked for me.